# "imagine on one side" vs "on one side imagine" vs sth else?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, sentence-choice

"Enter into your imagination, and **imagine on one side** several people who have yelled at you. On the second side imagine all those who have supported you".

"Imagine on one side", "On one side imagine" or how would you write it by other words?
I think "on one side imagine" would be more clear in that case, but I also know that generally adjunct is after verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like your suggestion, but I think more commas would help both variants:

- and imagine, on one side, several people who have yelled at you.
- and[,] on one side, imagine...

The bracketed comma is optional.

I would rephrase the whole thing myself, though, to clarify. "Imagine a giant hall, with all those who have chastized you lined up on side and all those who have supported you lined up on the other", or something like that.